# How to code a simple connected component labeling with MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, connected-components

```
+---------------+
|               |                              
|  white        |          
|               |                                                      
+------+        |                 +---------------+
       |        |                 |               |
       |        |                 |   white       |
       +--------+                 |               |           
                                  |               |
                                  +---------------+


     +--------------------------+                                  black
     |                          |           
     |                          |
     |      white               |
     |                          |
     |                          |                                      
     +--------------------------+
```

---

How can I label and colorize the 3 shapes for a simple image (like above).

- using connected component analysis with 8 neighborhood
- the shapes are white colored and the outside is black
- each of the shapes will get a color like blue, green, etc.
- should be a simple code (with MATLAB) which processes the image pixel by pixel according to connected component analysis

Thank you for any help.

Comment: And what have you tried? Did you try google with the exact terms from your question? When I do I find a nice tutorial by The Mathworks on how to do exactly that.

Comment: I tried to find from google. There are some codes which colorizes the shapes but the code seems little complex for me. And I couldn't understand whether it uses CCA. I didn't code in MATLAB till now. So, I am new in MATLAB and trying to find some help. If you have a good link from google, please share with me.

Comment: check [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/labeling-and-measuring-objects-in-a-binary-image.html) out

Comment: The duplicate I have linked above performs CCA via Depth-First Search in MATLAB.  Once you obtain a map of which pixels belong to which object, you can loop over each unique ID and colour the objects with whatever colour you desire.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you **Benoit_11** & **rayryeng**.